# could this integral be solved using substitution?

Tags: calculus, integration, substitution, integration-by-parts

I'm struggling to integrate $$\int{\frac{\sqrt{x+1}}{x^2}}$$ I already know the answer after i used by parts. But could this be found using substitution instead and not integration by parts?

I made $u=\sqrt{x+1}$ and got $$2\int{\frac{u^2}{(u^2-1)^2}}$$ and then used long division to integrate further. have i made a mistake?

Comment: Isn't that supposed to be $(u^2-1)^2$ on the denominator?

Comment: yes , let me fix that. but afterwards will i be able to use sub?

Comment: @electro7912 try to shift the indices of the problem maybe so you can factor the integral?

Comment: @Deepak  i think that was the mistake that was holding me back. Never realized  it but i should be able to solve it now . Thanks

Comment: @electro7912 Well, if you hadn't realised your mistake, you'd have had an even easier integral, to be honest. $\frac{u^2}{u^2-1} = 1 + \frac{1}{u^2-1}$ and the second term is very easy to PF decompose. (of course, the final answer would've been wrong).